# Removal of shadow from Matlab image for recognition of seeds of plants

Tags: matlab

I am working recognition of plant seeds with Matlab, and I am looking for code to remove the shadow in grayscale and binary.

[image: image of seed with shadow]

The binarized version of the image is:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on where you are having trouble.  Questions only asking for code are likely to be closed.

Comment: You can do a lot of things here, an immediate and obvious one is contrast thresholding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision). The other technique you can apply is segmentation, something like http://goo.gl/th7T8h. But we need to know what you have tried so far, to give you a clear cut solution.

Comment: ![this is how the image looks when i convert to binary](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2NZW7.png) and i need it with out the shadow.am new to matlab, i have tried so many codes and havent still gotten the right one yet.
thank u all for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the "rice grains" tutorial?
[(a)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html) [(b)](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexrice.html) [(c)](http://cronos.rutgers.edu/~lrr/dsp%20design%20course/lectures_2012_new/pdf_2012/Lecture3c_2012.pdf) [(d)](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/images/getting3.html)

I suspect that feeding your image into the process described in the "rice grains" tutorial,
with minor tweaks -- perhaps changing the

```
background = imopen(I,strel('disk',15));
```

step to perhaps something more like

```
background = imopen(I,strel('disk',600));
```

would produce a images closer to what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose 2 methods.

1) The easy one:

Saturation value of shadows are generally very low. So convert your image to HSV domain. Obtain S channel (saturation) and threshold it. For this specific example, threshold value $100$ gives you the following:

[image]

2) More Sophisticated: Shadow removal problem is generally tackled using intrinsic images. They are pretty straightforward to compute and various resources exist on that literature. To begin with, I would suggest:

http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~jfrank8/ecse626/ecse626-project-jordan-frank.pdf